# How to always find the newest blog post with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

How can I select the first post in the new posts section at publish0x.com/newposts with selenium?
The post will always be in the same spot on the page but the title and author will vary.

The page where the posts are located: https://www.publish0x.com/newposts
An example of a post: https://www.publish0x.com/dicecrypto-articles/welcome-to-altseason-as-major-altcoins-explodes-xmkmvkk

Comment: can you share url of posts ?

Comment: Edited the question to include some URLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a list of all the posts, and then extract the first element:

```
driver.get('https://www.publish0x.com/newposts')
post = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main > div.infinite-scroll > div:nth-child(1) > div.content')
```

and now you can extract the author name and title from the post like:

```
title = post.find_element_by_css_selector('h2 > a').text
author = post.find_element_by_css_selector(p.text-secondary > small:nth-child(4) > a').text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://www.publish0x.com/newposts");
       
        List<WebElement> LIST = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class="infinite-scroll"]//div/descendant::div[@class="content"]"));
        System.out.println(LIST.size());
LIST.get(0).click();
```

use above xpath to click 1 st post ( this is java code, you can use same xpath for python)
try this and let me know